# Insert big number of rows into Postgres DB using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I'm trying to insert over 1 million rows into Postgres Table using NodeJs
The problem is when i start script, the memory constantly keep increasing till it reach 1.5 GB of RAM and then I get error: 
FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - process out of memory

The result always the same - about 7000 inserted rows instead of 1 million

Here is the code

```
var pg = require('pg');
var fs = require('fs');
var config = require('./config.js');



var PgClient = new pg.Client(config.pg);
PgClient.connect();

var lineReader = require('readline').createInterface({
      input: require('fs').createReadStream('resources/database.csv') //file contains over 1 million lines
    });
var n=0;




lineReader.on('line', function(line) {
      n++;
      var insert={"firstname":"John","lastname":"Conor"};

      //No matter what data we insert, the point is that the number of inserted rows much less than it should be 
      PgClient.query('INSERT INTO HUMANS (firstname,lastname) values ($1,$2)', [insert.firstname,insert.lastname]);

});

lineReader.on('close',function() {
     console.log('end '+n); 
});
```

Comment: Have you tried pausing once you get a line and resuming once the query's callback has been called? I think there are too many queries being queued up, and that's what may be exhausting your process memory.

Comment: I aded lineReader.pause();  before query and lineReader.resume(); after query but looks like that didn't work. The same error

Comment: Consider doing bulk inserts instead. Inserting on a per row basis is too expensive.

Comment: @m3n1at You mean you added a callback to your `PgClient.query()` call and inside there is where you called `lineReader.resume()`?

Comment: @mscdex Yes, I did it. Problem the same - FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - process out of memory

Comment: I think it's probably be better to ditch readline and just DIY, that way you can immediately stop when you see a newline and resume inside the query callback. Otherwise readline could emit `line` many times before the query callback is called (rendering the `pause()`/`resume()` usage useless).

Comment: I made some research with debugger and found out that queries are queued and executed only when the file is read, so when the file is large the memory is overflowed. (with 200 000 lines file everything works fine)
So is there a way to force inserts in queue to be executed each let's say 10 000 lines ?

Comment: Best read for this: [Data Imports](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/wiki/Data-Imports).

Answer (score 3):

I used pg-promise as vitaly-t suggested. And this code works realy fast

```
const fs = require('fs');
const pgp = require('pg-promise')();
const config = require('./config.js');

// Db connection
const db = pgp(config.pg);

// Transform a lot of inserts into one
function Inserts(template, data) {
    if (!(this instanceof Inserts)) {
        return new Inserts(template, data);
    }
    this._rawType = true;
    this.toPostgres = () => {
        return data.map(d => '(' + pgp.as.format(template, d) + ')').join();
    };
}

// insert Template
function Insert() {
      return {
          firstname:   null,
          lastname:    null,
          birthdate:     null,
          phone:    null,
          email:   null,
          city: null,
          district:    null,
          location: null,
          street: null
      };
};
const lineReader = require('readline').createInterface({
      input: require('fs').createReadStream('resources/database.csv')
    });


let n = 0;
const InsertArray = [];

lineReader.on('line', function(line) {   
      var insert = new Insert();
      n ++;   
      var InsertValues=line.split(',');
      if (InsertValues[0]!=='"Firstname"'){ //skip first line
          let i = 0;
          for (let prop in insert){
              insert[prop] = (InsertValues[i]=='')?insert[prop]:InsertValues[i];
              i++;
          }
          InsertArray.push(insert);
          if (n == 10000){
              lineReader.pause();
              // convert insert array into one insert
              const values = new Inserts('${firstname}, ${lastname},${birthdate},${phone},${email},${city},${district},${location},${street}', InsertArray);
              db.none('INSERT INTO users (firstname, lastname,birthdate,phone,email,city,district,location,street) VALUES $1', values)
                .then(data => {
                    n = 0;
                    InsertArray=[];
                    lineReader.resume();
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error);
                });
          }
      }
});


lineReader.on('close',function() {
     console.log('end '+n); 
     //last insert
     if (n > 0) {
         const values = new Inserts('${firstname}, ${lastname},${birthdate},${phone},${email},${city},${district},${location},${street}', InsertArray);
         db.none('INSERT INTO users (firstname, lastname,birthdate,phone,email,city,district,location,street) VALUES $1', values)
            .then(data => {
                console.log('Last');
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
     }
});
```

Comment: Best example: [Data Imports](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/wiki/Data-Imports).

Comment: I've updated the code example for compliance with the latest pg-promise v6.5.0

Answer (score -1):

So i resolved the issue. There is PgClient.queryQueue which is processed with much less speed than reading of file. And when big file is read the queue is overflowed.
And here the solution, we should change lineReader.on('line',cb) section, every time the queue has a lot of elements we pause lineReader

```
lineReader.on('line', function(line) {
      n++;
      var insert={"firstname":"John","lastname":"Conor"};
      PgClient.query('INSERT INTO HUMANS (firstname,lastname) values ($1,$2)', [insert.firstname,insert.lastname],function (err,result){
          if (err) console.log(err);
          if (PgClient.queryQueue.length>15000) {
              lineReader.pause(); 
          }
          else lineReader.resume(); 
      });
});
```

Comment: This a bad solution, while the right one is trivial - read lines from the file in batches, of some 1000-10,000 inserts, and insert each such read as a batch. Also, you need to concatenate inserts - see [Performance Boost](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/wiki/Performance-Boost).